# How do I know if the home screen is in focus?

Tags: android

I have an service running on Android and I need to know if is any application on focus or if the "desktop" (home screen) is in focus. I don't know if this is the proper word to refer to the home screen of the phone. How can I know if this is in focus or some other application?

Inside the service I have this code to get the running tasks:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
// get the info from the currently running task
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
```

How can I know from `componentInfo` if this is desktop or no? On emulator the componentInfo.getPackageName() returns `com.android.launcher` but in a Galaxy S1 (I tested only in this phone) returns something else.

There is any other way to do this?

Comment: "I need to know if is any application on focus or if the "desktop" (home screen) is in focus" -- why?

Comment: My impression is that you cannot *reliably* determine this.  And realize that home screen replacements are a category of app too.

Comment: it's less important why. in few words, I build an app that helps parents to protect their phone if a 2-4 years kid wants to play on the phone. And for this app I need to do something when the kid goes to homescreen.

Comment: @ZelterAdy Android really doesn't respond well to trying to backseat drive the user experience - CommonsWare gives you the most plausible approximate solution with the replacement home screen idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get control when "the home screen is in focus", implement a home screen.

Comment: I don't need  to implement a home screen, just to prevent specific users (kids) to use it. For this reason I need to know when the home screen is the top activity.

Comment: @ZelterAdy: And the way for you "to know when the home screen is the top activity" is for you to be the home screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All the home screens should have something common, is it? How the operating system recognize an app as home screen?

Comment: can u please give me a link to a tutorial that teaches me how to build an home screen? Thanks.

Comment: @ZelterAdy: I do not have a home screen tutorial link handy, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

```java
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName currentTask = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
mPackageManager = getPackageManager();

List<ResolveInfo> appList = mPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {
    ResolveInfo apl = appList.get(i);
    if(currentTask.getPackageName().equals(apl.activityInfo.packageName)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ONHOMESCREEN");
    }
}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml you need permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: Works on Android 7 still. woohoo

Answer (score 1):

Try this function,

```
    public boolean isUserIsOnHomeScreen()
{
    ActivityManager manager = 
            (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes)
    {
        if(process.pkgList[0].equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.launcher"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return false;

}
```