# How to know whether home screen is focused

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, launcher

I am developing an android application which runs a Service in background that will only run when user will on home screen. I followed this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660275/android-how-do-i-know-if-the-home-screen-is-in-focus#answer-25555993), but it always require to hit this method to get the answer. I am using the following code.

```
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                detect();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
    }

    void detect(){
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName currentTask = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        mPackageManager = getPackageManager();

        List<ResolveInfo> appList = mPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {
            ResolveInfo apl = appList.get(i);
            if(currentTask.getPackageName().equals(apl.activityInfo.packageName)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ONHOMESCREEN");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any solution by `BroadcastReceiver`  to receive by `Intent` whether home screen is on focus or not?

Please Help....